# How to hide unhandled errors in next js?

Tags: node.js, next.js, error-handling, unhandled

I was facing error in next js site so i need to hide it
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkQFD.png]

i've added this in "app.js" file and its working so it may also help you if you face this kind of issue

```
const noOverlayWorkaroundScript = `
  window.addEventListener('error', event => {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation()
  })

  window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', event => {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation()
  })
`
```

`<script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: noOverlayWorkaroundScript }} />`

Comment: Hi Jigar, thank you for sharing your thoughts. My two cents: The solution you provide is, in my eyes, a 'hack' and not a solution of any problem. This is a bad practice and should not be used by others.